# Disable visual style for a single CButton

Tags: mfc

If I create normal `CButtons` they look like this:

[image: Button with visual styles enabled]

I accidentally created some older looking buttons when I did the following:

```
class CClickButton : public CButton
{
    afx_msg int OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs);
    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CClickButton);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP();
};

IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CClickButton, CButton);

BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CClickButton, CButton)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

int CClickButton::OnCreate (LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs)
{
    return 0;
}
```

[image: Button with an older look]

Now I would like to create buttons in this style. (Because I want to add a bitmap. And only when using this style, they give a visual feedback of getting 'pushed down'. The new style just tints the background blue and this is hidden by the bitmap on top of the button. An alternative question would be, if there is an easy way to also tint the image when the button gets pressed.)

What is the proper way to tell MFC to create those kind of buttons? Just omitting the the `OnCreate` message to the base class feels wrong to me. And I am not sure if that leads to other side effects I am not aware of yet.

I found some information on how to change the visual style for a whole program. But I only want to change it for some selected buttons.

Comment: How a button looks like is depending on either the manifest in your DLL or EXE or depending on API calls you do.

When the normal button look like your first sample others buttons should look the same when you have an according manifest.
Do you have a manifest? Who creates the button. Code in the EXE or in a DLL?

Comment: If I overwrite the `OnCreate` function, as I explained, I can create both types of buttons next to each other. The buttons are coming from a DLL. I am not aware of a manifest. But I did not create the application.

Comment: Buttons in the first style only be created when the application/DLL has a manifest vor ComCtrl 32 Version 6.0! ... If you have a DLL you my need a manifest (Afaik ID24 too) Read the MSDN about his.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Visual styles can be enabled and disabled on a per-window basis. The MSDN provides information on how to [Turn Off Visual Styles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175.aspx#turnoff):

> You can turn off visual styles for a control or for all controls in a window by calling the [**SetWindowTheme**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759827.aspx) function as follows:
>
> ```
> SetWindowTheme(hwnd, L" ", L" ");
> ```

---

To implement this in your MFC `CButton`-derived class, put the code in your `OnCreate`-handler:

```
int CClickButton::OnCreate( LPCREATESTRUCT lpcs ) {
    ::SetWindowTheme( m_hWnd, L" ", L" " );
    return CButton::OnCreate( lpcs );
}
```

---

If you are using a dialog resource to build your GUI and attach your `CClickButton` to an existing standard button control using the [DDX_Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z04ab59a.aspx) function after the dialog (and its controls) have been created, your `OnCreate`-handler will not get called. For this specific scenario you will have to turn off visual styles at a later point. An ideal candidate is overriding the virtual `PreSubclassWindow` method:

```
void CClickButton::PreSubclassWindow() {
    ::SetWindowTheme( m_hWnd, L" ", L" " );
    CButton::PreSubclassWindow();
}
```